# Kra's theorem of Pseudo-Anosov maps

Tags: reference-request, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory

Let $S$ be a surface of negative Euler characteristic. Consider the Birman exact sequence:

$$1\xrightarrow{ }\pi_1(S,p)\xrightarrow{P} Mod(S,p)\xrightarrow{ }Mod(S)\xrightarrow{ }1$$

In his paper [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02392465), Kra proved that if $\gamma\in \pi_1(S,p)$ then $P(\gamma)$ is pseudo-Anosov if and only if $\gamma$ fills $S$ (see [Theorem 14.6](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9495.html) for a simple proof).

Kra's original proof consider two numbers:

1) $K$, which is the dilatation of the map $P(\gamma)\in Mod(S,p)$ on Teichmuller space $\mathcal{T}(S,p)$.

2) $\lambda=exp(2l)$, where $l$ is the minimum of the length function of $\gamma$ on Teichmuller space $\mathcal{T}(S,p)$.

Excluding thrice punctured sphere, he proved that $$K<\lambda.$$

At the end of this paper Kra said that "The precise relation between $K$ and $\lambda$ should be clarified by future investigation."

I want to know what is the current status of research related to Kra's above statement.

PS 1): Individually the number $K$ has been studied by many people. For details see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3936).

PS 2) If $\gamma$ is a filling curve, then by convexity of length function, there is a unique point $X\in\mathcal{T}(S,p)$ where the minimum length $l$ is achieved (see [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/kerckhoff/nielsen/nielsen.pdf)).